# SystemVerilog Clocking Blocks in Bi-Directional Interface

Tags: system-verilog

Let's say I have a bi-directional interface.  I want the TB to be able to receive data from the DUT and I want the TB to be able to drive data to the DUT.  I need to put in a `clocking` block in my code because I have race-condition issues.  I can fix these issues by putting in a little #1 in the right spot, but I know that a clocking block is the correct solution.  The part I'm having difficulty with is the bi-directional part.  If it was one direction I might be OK, but the syntax for bi-directional interface is tripping me up.  Is the right solution to make 2 clocking blocks, or 2 modports, or something else entirely?

```
interface MyInterface
  (input bit i_Clk);

  logic [15:0] r_Data;
  logic        r_DV = 1'b0;

  clocking CB @(posedge i_Clk);
    default input #1step output #1step;    
  endclocking : CB

  task t_Clock_Cycles(int N);
    repeat (N) @(posedge i_Clk);
  endtask : t_Clock_Cycles

  modport Driver   (clocking CB, output r_Data, r_DV);
  modport Receiver (clocking CB, input  r_Data, r_DV);

endinterface : MyInterface


package MyPackage;

  class MyDriver;
    virtual MyInterface.Driver hook;

    function new(virtual MyInterface.Driver hook);
      this.hook    = hook;
    endfunction : new

    task t_Drive(input [15:0] i_Data);
      forever
        begin
          hook.CB.r_Data = i_Data;
          hook.CB.r_DV   = 1'b1;
          hook.CB.t_Clock_Cycles(1);
        end
    endtask : t_Drive

  endclass : MyDriver

endpackage : MyPackage


module MyModule;
  import MyPackage::*;
  logic r_Clk = 1'b0;
  MyInterface hook(.i_Clk(r_Clk));
  always #5 r_Clk = ~r_Clk;
  MyDriver d1   = new(hook.Driver);

  initial
    begin
      d1.t_Drive(16'hABCD);
    end
endmodule // MyModule
```

Comment: You're going to have too elaborate a bit on what you mean with bidirectionality. I only see a driver in there that can drive your 'data' signal.

Comment: You're using blocking assignments (`=`) to ports which I think you want to be synchronous. This could be a source of your race conditions. Change them to `<=` and it might help.

Comment: @Tudor, you're right, I didn't include the receiver class, but I do have one.

Comment: What I meant was an `inout` signal. Your signal has a defined direction, from driver to receiver. It's just that you want each of them to have different permissions w.r.t. what they're allowed to do with the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of using a clocking block is to declare which signals you want to access synchronously. You should add your signals to the clocking block:

```
clocking CB @(posedge i_Clk);
  default input #1step output #1step;
  inout r_Data;
  inout r_DV;
endclocking : CB
```

Since you also want to have different access permissions for your driver and receiver, this means you'll need two different clocking blocks:

```
clocking CB_driver @(posedge i_Clk);
  default input #1step output #1step;
  output r_Data;
  output_DV;
endclocking : CB_driver

// ... direction reversed for CB_receiver
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to say that you have a reference to a certain clocking block inside your driver/receiver classes:

```
class Driver
  virtual MyInterface.CB_driver hook;  // !!! Not allowed
endclass
```

If you want to restrict your driver to only be able to drive through `CB_driver`, you can use a `modport`:

```
interface MyInterface;
  modport Driver(CB_driver);
endinterface

class Driver;
  virtual MyInterface.Driver hook;
endclass
```

This way you can reference `hook.CB_driver` when driving your signals. The same goes for your receiver.